# Why does my C code and Python code take more time just for itration in for loop

Tags: python, c, optimization, dynamic-programming, labview

I have a Python code and a C code.

My Python code is this:

```py
import os
import time
count = 0
number_of_itration =100000000
begin = time.time()
for i in range(number_of_itration):
    count += 1
end = time.time()
print(f'Sum is {count}')
print(f"Total runtime of the program is {end - begin} Seconds")
```

This code takes 12 seconds to execute.

I have a similar C Code:

```c
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (InitCVIRTE (0, argv, 0) == 0)
        return -1;
    start_t = clock();
    for(i=0; i< 100000000; i++) 
    {
        count= count+1;
    }
    end_t = clock();
    total_t = (double)(end_t - start_t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Total time taken by CPU: %f\n", total_t  );
    RunUserInterface ();
    
    return 0;
}
```

This takes 0.395 seconds.

And I have a labview code:

[image: Labview code]

Which takes just 0.093 seconds.

Where am I going wrong? I was expecting C to run faster.

My C IDE is Lab windows CVI, which is from National Instruments.

My system configuration is:

[image: System Configuration]

How can I optimize C code for processor?

Comment: Have you built the C code with optimizations enabled? [If I fix all the errors and build with optimizations, then the loop will disappear](https://godbolt.org/z/nW51o8chG), and the program will be extremely quick. As a general rule, benchmarking should only be done on optimized builds.

Comment: @Julien It was a mistake, its actually 0.093 seconds for labview

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude im actually trying to convince once of my client to go with C code than python, but since C is giving me 300 ms, and slower than lab view, i cant say that. Im using a labwindows CVI IDe, how can  i optimize my code over there? is this related to build?

Comment: As a benchmark program, the code is useless. As shown in my link, a compiler will just skip the loop if you build with optimizations enabled, making the "total time" `0.000002` (or less) seconds. Also be careful when using `clock` to benchmark, as it measures different things on different platforms (on POSIX platforms like Linux or macOS it measures CPU time, on Windows it follows the wall clock).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so according to you, how can i check is python or C is faster?, what should be the criteria ?

Comment: You have to create a test around an actual use-case of your client.

Comment: Python code will typically run slower (for the same functionality) as it's interpreted whereas C/C++ is compiled. Also, just as an aside, your Python code runs in 6.4s on my machine so your platform for testing is clearly below par

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this much more similar to my client use case 
Mostly my program uses Reading from large text file(500mb -1 GB files) Writing to large text file, may sequences etc

Comment: @Stuart im using visual studio code, with same machine where i run labview and C, Isthere any optimization for python on  VS code?

Comment: @Altroz You can run your Python code with the -O flag but that won't improve this particular case. It's your hardware that's not ideal

Comment: @SupportUkraine I have option to develop code in all the three language, where python im not an expert b coz the requirement is a pretty complex system engaging around 15-20 threads acquiring data and processing it in another thread, so i doubt if python can handle it, all my hardware are from NI so i needed to convince client to either go with C Or lab view

Comment: The Labview timing is suspicious. It would correspond to 2.6 clock cycles per iteration, which is really little. Can you show the documentation for this block ? By the way, don't base your judgment on these toy programs, which are full of biases.

Comment: If you plan to do IO-bound operations like reading/writing large text files, then make sure you use a SSD or the file can be cached by the operating system. HDD will make such operation very slow if not cached whatever the language used. With caching it is faster on HDD but not great if the file is big and the RAM limited. With SSD it is significantly faster and using a compiled language often helps a lot. This is especially true with good NVMe SSD (with a typical throughput 5-50 times faster than HDD and IOPS 100-5000 times faster than a HDD -- so the gap is huge).

Comment: @JérômeRichard we are planing for NVMe SSD with 10G speed  and 32 Gb of ram with i9 processor

Comment: The NI hardware usually have full C# support. Usually that is a good midway between C and a interpreted language for performance vs features.

Answer (score 1):

If you have debugging turned off, LabVIEW will constant fold that For Loop during compilation. It won't take any time at all to execute because it'll all reduce to a single pre-computed constant value. Change the input to the For Loop's shift register from a constant to a control and add the control to the connector pane. You should see the time increase to be about equal to the C code. I suspect if you change your compile options on the C code, you'd see the time there decrease.

Python doesn't do those kinds of optimizations.